# Capitalization of String using Regex

Tags: java, regex

Is it possible to convert a upper case string into lower case using regex?

I currently have this code:

```
strFileText = strFileText.replaceAll("COMMITTEE ON ", "committee on ");
```

instead of `("COMMITTEE ON ", "committee on ");` can I write an regex?

Comment: You need to clarify what exactly you need. Do you need to do only those specific replacements? Lower case EVERYTHING? Lower case only specific words?

Comment: Why don't you simply use String#toUpperCase() ? What is your goal ?

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions on their own can't do case-conversion.

But you can easily combine regex with any programmatic replacement that you can write in Java using [`Matcher.appendReplacement()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
public String replaceLowerCase(final String input, final String pattern) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find()) {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group().toLowerCase());
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

And you can call it like this:

```
System.out.println(replaceLowerCase(myInput, "COMMITTEE ON");
```

Comment: @joachim Sauer how can i check whether input is in uppercase or in lowercase.My goal is when ever a upper case text has come i want to convert it into lower case.

Comment: @user2469963 if you convert each text to lowercase whatever comes as input,  it does not get any difference. but anyways if you want to do it manually you can check ASCII of input char i.e. `if(inputchar>=65 && inputchar<=90)` convert into lowercase.

Comment: @Bhumika: I *strongly* discourage doing this based on ASCII numbers. You'll break everything that doesn't use ASCII exclusively. ä, ö, ü, İ and Å are just a few of the characters that you'll mis-detect this way.

Comment: @JoachimSauer oops!! ok, thanks to point this one and correct also.

Comment: @user2469963: why would you want to detect that? `"a".toLowerCase()` is simply `a`, so no harm done. If you could explain your *entire* use-case, that would help us solve your *actual* problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can  use `toLowerCase()` for that

> Converts all of the characters in this String to lower case using the
>   rules of the default locale. This is equivalent to calling
>   toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).

[**SEE HERE**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `string.toLowerCase()` instead of regex.